# Remove image from content and put it to the very first of it

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to move just the first `<img>` to the very first place in a `<description>` in an XML feed. I want to change this:

```
$html =
'this is content and this is the 1st image <img src="first_image.jpg"> within the text and <img src="second_image.jpg"> is the second one.'
```

to this:

```
$html = '<img src="the_source.jpg">
    this is content and this is the 1st image within the text and <img src="second_image.jpg"> is the second one.'
```

using DOMDocument in php. I have this right now:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
if($image = $xpath->query('.//img[1]')){
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMXPath::query` returns always a DOMNodeList object (even if there is a single node in the list), thus you need to take the first item (that is a DOMNode object) to use the parentNode property:

```
if($image = $xpath->query('//img[1]')){
    $node = $image->item(0);
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($node);
    $parent->insertBefore($node, $parent->firstChild);
}
```

---

About your specific rss feed, it seems that the description tag is not the immediate ancestor of the img node. you can try this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('./rssfeed.xml');
$xml = html_entity_decode($xml, ENT_XML1, "UTF-8");
$xml = preg_replace('~<img\s[^>]*\K(?<!/)>~', '/>', $xml);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$descNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(1);
$imgNode = $descNode->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);

$imgNode->parentNode->removeChild($imgNode);
$descNode->insertBefore($imgNode, $descNode->firstChild);
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML());
```

If you want to preserve htmlentities:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('./rssfeed.xml');
$descNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(1);
$contentText = $descNode->nodeValue;
$imgTag = '';
$contentText = preg_replace_callback('~<img\s[^>]*>~',
                      function($m) use (&$imgTag) { $imgTag = $m[0]; return; },
                      $contentText, 1);
$descNode->nodeValue = htmlentities($imgTag . $contentText);
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: thanks for ur response. this adds it to the very first as wanted in question body, or just removes it?

Comment: @Arash: Sorry I haven't fully read the question, I believed you only want to delete it. Wait a minute.

Comment: It is ok with DIV, but I can not get it to work in real case, as I am going to put the first image, into very first place of description node of an XML feed. what to do? please help

Comment: @Arash: in this case, in the last line, instead of the parent node, choose the node you need. And take a look to phpdoc for  the `insertBefore` method.

Comment: I put some hours on it, but it looks like I am not able to get it done. please help me put this at very first place of text within `<description>` of the feed xml. thanks:)

Comment: @Arash: In this case, post your XML feed somewhere (ideone or an other online editor) and give me the link, I will take a look.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did we have any progress on the thing?

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. please consider it is the direct child of `<description>`, because I pre-parse the feed xml. just consider it

Comment: thanks alot. Are we supposed to do it using regex? I have read much about not to parse html with regex on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Arash: In the first example, if you want to obtain self-closing img tags that are xml compliant, you need to add a slash before the closing angle bracket. In the second example, we are not parsing xml with a regex but only the value of an `XML_TEXT_NODE`, that indeed looks like html, but is not an `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`. In general, the best  is to find the most appropriate solution for a specific problem, and to make his own opinion wihtout putting obstacle in your own way.